# Tweepy: about accessing the "id" of a user after a Pagination response

Tags: python, data-structures, twitter, tweepy, paginator

I'm really stuck on this one.

I'm using Tweepy to get the IDs of all users that liked a specific tweet. I seem to get a list of "User" structures that contain "id", "name" and "username", but I'm not able to get only the "id".

The code is simple:

```
client = tweepy.Client(
    bearer_token=bearer_token,
    consumer_key=api_key, consumer_secret=api_secret,
    access_token=user_token, access_token_secret=user_token_secret,
    wait_on_rate_limit=True
)

for response in tweepy.Paginator(client.get_liking_users, id=tweetid, max_results=100, limit=10):
    for item in response:
        print("ITEM:\n", item)
        if item is not None:
            for user in item:
                if user is not None:
                    print(user)
```

The print of "item" gets me this (simplified, of course; the number of structures is high, that's why I have to use Paginator):

```
[<User id=0000001 name=user1 username=UserName1>, <User id=0002 name=user2 username=UserName2>, <User id=000003 name=user3 username=UserName3>]
```

and the print of "user" just gets me the individual usernames: "UserName1", etc.

But no way to get user.id, user.User.id, nor anything similar. And I'm frustrated, because the information is right there, just I can't access it easily.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tweepy documentation provides an example of something very similar to what you want to do: https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/examples.html -> API v2 -> Get Tweet’s Liking Users

```py
import tweepy


bearer_token = ""

client = tweepy.Client(bearer_token)

# Get Tweet's Liking Users

# This endpoint/method allows you to get information about a Tweet’s liking
# users

tweet_id = 1460323737035677698

# By default, only the ID, name, and username fields of each user will be
# returned
# Additional fields can be retrieved using the user_fields parameter
response = client.get_liking_users(tweet_id, user_fields=["profile_image_url"])

for user in response.data:
    print(user.username, user.profile_image_url)
```

This example prints the user's username and profile image URL, but note the comment says the id is also returned, so something like `user.id` should work. Otherwise, you can also add `id` to `user_fields` to make sure it's returned, although that shouldn't be necessary.

Unfortunately, I am not able to test it myself because I don't have a Twitter developer account with the required elevated access.

*Edit: I got access to an API account with elevated access and I was able to test your code, see the update below*

## Iterating paginated results

The reason why you need a double `for` loop to iterate the paginated results and it eventually crashes after showing some results with an error saying you are trying to access a non-existent `id` attribute on an `str` object is because you are not iterating the `Paginator` results correctly.

For the sake of simplicity, I'm going to label your three nested `for` loops:

loop 0: `for response in tweepy.Paginator(...`
loop 1: `for item in response`
loop 2: `for user in item`

`Paginator` returns a `Response` object with all the results in the `data` attribute. The object has other attributes like `meta`, `count`, etc.

When you do loop 1, you are iterating all these `data`, `count`, etc., attributes of `Response`.

If the attribute you are iterating happens to be the `data` attribute, it will start loop 2 and it will iterate the results getting the output you expect.

But loop 1 will also iterate other `Reponse` items outside of the `data` attribute.

Let's see, for example, what happens when loop 1 enters the `meta` attribute.

`meta` is a dictionary that looks like this:

```
meta={'result_count': 80, 'next_token': '676f9b7bumw8i3jbm4nnifamw2ejjaktp8kjym6akdak9'}
```

When you enter loop 2 with the `meta` attribute, it will start iterating the keys (not the values, because that's how dicts work in Python) so the value of `user` in loop 2 will be either `result_count` or `next_token`. And it's then when you are getting your error saying you are trying to access `id` on a `str`.

What you should be doing is iterating the `response.data` in loop 1 instead and that will also allow removing the need of a second loop:

```py
for response in tweepy.Paginator(client.get_liking_users, id=tweetid, max_results=100, limit=10):
    for user in response.data:
        print(user.id)
```

*Edit: grammar and style*

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I was aware of that example, but unfortunately, the step through "Paginator" seems to make the response different in that regard: trying to get "user.username", that should work according to the example, gives in my case "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'username'".

Adding "id" to "user_fields" don't help either, alas.

Comment: The update did the trick!! Thanks a lot, it worked perfectly!!!